# Display image with Chromecast

Tags: android, chromecast, nanohttpd

I'm developing a gallery app and I want it to be compatible with the Chromecast.
I searched and tried for days but I can't get it to work. I learned that I need to create a webserver (NanoHTTPD) and send the url of the image. Can someone show me a simple tutorial?

If I have the path of the image, how can I display it in the simplest way possible?

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried https://developers.google.com/cast/ ?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't explain how to display a LOCAL image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is plenty of examples and resources that show you how to cast a video, so familiarize yourself with that. Then, for sending an image, you need to follow the same steps but your [MediaInfo](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/MediaInfo) object that represents your item (image in this case) needs to have its URL set to the url of the image, served by your embedded server (for example, if you put that url in your web browser on your laptop on the same network, you should be able to see the image). Then load that media item the same way you would load a video. For the simplest solution, you can use the [default receiver](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/receiver_apps#default); it supports images.